# Is it true that $[N*a]=N*[a]$?

Tags: calculus, approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $[\cdot]$ denote closest integer of a real number. Is it true that
$$
[N*a]=N*[a]
$$
where $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Of course no. Otherwise writing $1.63$ wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not necessary. Let $N=3$ and $a=2.5$, then

$[N\times a]=[3\times 2.5]=[7.5]=7$

$N\times [a]=3\times [2.5]=3\times 2=6$.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Let $N=10, a=0.3$.  Try it.